# How to use android OS component to build Own device (e.g Camera)

Tags: java, android, linux, open-source

I want to build my own little camera that use Smart Operating system, Now building it from scratch  needs lot of time and resources which i dont have, 
So i was wondering is there any way i can download Android source code, Change the way  i want and use it in my little project.

So that means i will not be needing android in-built phone or browser application and use only components that i need for  camera and use it on hardware.

There is couple of other questions:

Do i need google permission to use android?
Do i need to have any permission to modify android?

and lastly, how can i both download android source and unzip it to use it(if any one found tutorial on this will be great since i'm trying to find all this for last few hours and sims to there is nothing that covers all in one)

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about only `camera`, but you can download source code & build in any device.

Here ([Android Source code](http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html)) is full description about how to download & build source code in device.

Unoffically Android in Nokia

[Android 4.0 running on a Nokia N9](http://www.theverge.com/2012/3/22/2893830/nokia-n9-android-port-alpha)

[Nokia N900 gets Android 2.3 Unoffically](http://www.fonearena.com/blog/28040/nokia-n900-gets-android-2-3-unoffically.html)